# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que unos valores numéricos finitos se conviertan en NaN cuando realizo un cambio de índice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy realizando un programa para tratar una información con la que estoy trabajando. En el código abro un archivo *csv* para poder obtener lo que he etiquetado como `new`.

El problema ocurre cuando paso de `new1` a `new`. No se cómo pero unos valores que en `new1` aparecen correctamente en `new` se transforman en `NaN`. El cambio que realizo de `new1` a `new` es solamente un cambio en el índice.

A continuación os dejo el código que he escrito:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\User\openings.csv', ',', names = ['Interval', 'Numero', 'Temps'], index_col=False).T

new2 = pd.DataFrame(df[0])

k = 3  
for j in range(1,k+1):
    new2 = new2.join(pd.DataFrame(df[3*j]), lsuffix=j, rsuffix=j+1)

new1 = new2.drop(['Numero', 'Interval'], axis=0).T


new = new1.reindex(index = list(range(len(new1))))
```

He intentado varias formas de como cambiar el índice, pero en ninguna de ellas consigo mantener los valores iniciales. Me parece que el error está ahí, pero tampoco lo se....

Answer (score 0):

EL método `reindex()` de un `DataFrame` lo que hace es crear un nuevo `DataFrame` copiando valores del antiguo al nuevo, de modo que se preserve el índice.

Así, por ejemplo, si el `DataFrame` original tenía el valor `10` para el índice 3, en el nuevo "reindexado", también tendrá el valor `10` para ese mismo índice. Esto implica que si en el nuevo índice hay valores que no estaban en el índice antiguo, los rellenará con `NaN` (aunque puedes indicarle a `reindex()` que los rellene con cualquier otro valor que quieras, mediante el parámetro `fill_value`).

El siguiente ejemplo lo aclarará. Supón que tenemos un dataframe llamado `df` con el siguiente contenido:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
0     0
2     1
4     2
6     3
8     4
10    5
12    6
14    7
16    8
18    9
dtype: int64
```

Como ves, su índice sólo tiene valores pares. Si le aplico el `reindex()` como tú hiciste, obtengo `NaN` para todos los valores de índice impar:

```
In [4]: df.reindex(index=list(range(len(df))))
Out[4]:
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    NaN
4    2.0
5    NaN
6    3.0
7    NaN
8    4.0
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Sospecho que no es eso lo que pretendías. Si lo que querías es simplemente sustituir el índice original por otro nuevo que vaya de 0 a N, pero sin preservar los mismos valores para los mismos índices, la cosa es tan sencilla como `new1.reset_index()`.

Esto "borrará" el antiguo índice y lo sustiuirá por otro de enteros crecientes desde cero. El índice original te lo meterá en una nueva columna del dataframe llamada `index`, por si aún lo necesitas para otros procesamientos. En caso de que no lo necesites más puedes usar `new1.reset_index(drop=True)` para que lo descarte sin más.

```
In [5]: df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[5]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64

In [6]: df.reset_index()
Out[6]:
   index  0
0      0  0
1      2  1
2      4  2
3      6  3
4      8  4
5     10  5
6     12  6
7     14  7
8     16  8
9     18  9
```